# ASP.NET Core: Custom authentication and authorization

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core

Let's consider that I already have a package that returns `UserIdentity` based on `HttpRequest`. I want to create an ASP.NET Core project that uses my package in order to get ClaimIdentity object. How it could be done?

Comment: Consider checking out this article about Overview of ASP.NET Core authentication https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio and more specifically the linked article about ASP.NET Core middleware: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can tell Asp.NET Core to use your custom Identity by applying it on the services middleware registration. Something like

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<MyIdentityClass>()
```

Supposing that `MyIdentityClass` extends the `IdentityUser` class.
You can find more informations about how to customize the Identity [https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/aspnet/core/security/authentication/customize-identity-model?view=aspnetcore-3.1](here in the Asp.NET Core documentation)